# I just bought a horse that wants to kill me, how do I make friends?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So... I accidentally used one of my dragon shouts on a horse I just bought at the stable.

Now it wants to kill me, what can I do about it?

Comment: May I suggest not being a huge dick who yells at his horse?

Comment: @Wipqozn: I guess I have Dragonborn Tourette Syndrome. :(

Comment: Kill it & buy a new one. Or better yet get Shadowmere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try facing it close enough you can "activate" it and holding block and tapping the interact button several times, then sheath your weapon and it should be cool.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out I can sit on it. Although when I get off the horse he wants to kill me again, or did I not understand your answer?

Comment: @TomWijsman I think he means you need to "yield" to your horse - sheath your weapons in front of him (taking them out first if necessary)

Comment: yeah...thats what i meant...you yield to the horse and all should be good.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Oh, I'm new to the concept of [yielding](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Combat#Yielding). Thanks! :)

Comment: My evidence (sample size of one, however) indicates horses do not accept yields. However, my sample did not attempt to sit on the horse. I expect that's what did it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe use the calm spell? that might work