# Is it ever "legal" to steal from a slain enemy's home?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

A few times, I've had to vanquish an enemy in their home.

> Most recently, Nepos the Nose.

However, even after they're defeated, all of the possessions in their house are still marked as "Steal" instead of "Take".  Are there still negative consequences for taking things from the houses of a slain enemy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is still not legal even if the owner is dead.  Taking those items will still mark them as stolen in your inventory.  However, since there are no witnesses left, you will probably be able to get away with it.  On top of that, you are probably unlikely to be the target of some [payback](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/35269/3917) by the now dead owner.

Having said that, the only place you can sell those stolen goods is still through a fence (which requires joining the thieves guild).  And the items will still be taken away if you are ever arrested on some other charge.

Comment: You can also fence things through the Fence perk. (Speechcraft level 90)

Comment: Unlikely? Don't know if being dead affects the chance, but I've had payback exacted by a dead man before.

Comment: @MatthewScharley I think that the general consensus is the payback was initiated before they died. Don't have a reference right now.

Comment: I find it interesting that pickpocketing from NPCs is stealing while they're alive, but "legal" when they're dead - and yet death does not remove the illegal status of taking items from their homes.